# How to call a JS function from <bean> value tag?

Tags: javascript, html, spring

I have written following code:

```
<script>
function a(){
return 100;
}
</script>
<bean id="x" value="a()" />
```

How should I call a function from the bean-value parameter?

Comment: what is bean, I'm afraid there is no such tag as bean

Comment: <bean> tag is used in spring framework. You may refer the tag description [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to have `value="5"` in the end. Just use some js. It won't bite!

```
document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("value", a())
```

you can add that onload using

```
document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("value", a())
}
```

or by creating a function

```
function onload() {
    document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("value", a())
}
```

and calling it on load.

```
<body onload="onload()">
```

Comment: That sounds good! But in your case I will have to define   <bean id= "x"> without value parameter. HTML and Spring will not allow such definition